# Null Pointer exception when trying to layout inflate in service

Tags: android, service, nullpointerexception, layout-inflater

I'm trying to layout Inflate in a service on `onCreate` with this code:

```
// ...
public void onCreate() {    
    telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    call = new PhoneCall();

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(outgoingIntent);
    registerReceiver(callReceiver, intentFilter);

    final LayoutInflater myInflator = (LayoutInflater) ctext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );        

    onPhoneStatelistener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

// ...
```

Here is my log cat:

```
04-22 02:38:35.324: E/AndroidRuntime(28837): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 02:38:35.324: E/AndroidRuntime(28837): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.castello.AllMyCalls.CallService: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-22 02:38:35.324: E/AndroidRuntime(28837):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:1959)
04-22 02:38:35.324: E/AndroidRuntime(28837):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-22 02:38:35.324: E/AndroidRuntime(28837):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:989)
```

I'm just getting a "Null Pointer" error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post the logcat showing the NPE, and point out which line in your code is involved.

Comment: Where are you getting `null`? Is your `context` `null`?

Comment: More importantly, why are you trying to inflate a layout in a service? There's nothing that a service can do with an inflated layout.

Comment: @TedHopp I added my LogCat.

Comment: @CommonsWare I want to show a custom Toast when an outgoing call ends, so I have to do this, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

When i try to get `LayoutInflater` in service, i usually do like this :

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(Context);
```

Hope this might work for you!